# justification of step in complex integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

[image]

What is the justification for the step with the red square next to it, how do we change the integrator like this?

Comment: Isn't $ \phi_X(u) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty {\rm e}^{iuz} dF_X(z) $?